# tf.py_func InvalidArgumentError

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to wrap a python function into tensorflow using tf.py_func() and getting an InvalidArgumentError which I don't understand.
I'm passing two 2-d tensors and function returns a float value.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure without the code of your `distcorr() function`, but it seems that, as the error says, the function returns a `double` / `float64` while you are telling `tf.py_func()` to expect a `float32` (c.f. the `tf.float32` parameter).

Either modify your function to cast the results before returning it (e.g. `your_result.astype(numpy.float32)` or change the `dtype` parameter of `tf.py_func()` to `tf.float64`.

Comment: Thank you so much!